# The virtual keyboard and my UIView are fighting (drawing over each other constantly)

Tags: ios, uiview, keyboard, flicker

I have a UIViewController in which I have added a UIView to it with some UIButtons, and a UITextField to input the user's name.  When I select the UITextField and start typing on the virtual keyboard parts of it flicker in front of an behind the UIView, pieces of UIButtons come in front of the keyboard, etc.  This also happens with the paste operation, so for some reason the order of my UIView and the Keyboard appear to be the same?

What could possible cause this?

please see image @ http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/8606/iossimulatorscreenshotm.png

Comment: watch stanford video 15 - Editable Text, Modal View Controllers . you'll find answer for your question. Try implementing keyboard delegates so that you can move the view when keyboard is displayed.

Comment: I do move the view when the keyboard is displayed.

Comment: The video you recommend describes what I am doing already, it does not discuss anything about the issue I am having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked this down to "[self.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8f];" on my UIView.  For some reason, a modal view controller with a UIView who's shadow opacity is set causes the keyboard to flicker.

```
[self.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[self.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8f]; // this causes flickering with the keyboard.
[self.layer setShadowRadius:3.0f];
[self.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(2.0f, 2.0f)];
```

Comment: +1: Interesting. Was this happening on both the simulator and an actual device?

Comment: Yes, this happens on iPhone 4, iPhone 4S real devices and iPhone simulator.  I did not reposition it on the iPad to see if it happens there.